How to remove unused js and css from magento scandi pwa website
In website usually chunk css and js files will be generating while building. how to remove those unused css and js files from our sites to improve site performance.
is there any ways to avoid them and delete those chunk files which has been generated already.these sre chunk files in our websites how to remove them
